# Only allow some rows to be editable in ng-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I have an ng-grid that I would like to allow only certain rows to be editable.  It seems ng-grid is an all or nothing editable grid, am I missing something or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I came up with is to replace the cellEditTemplate in the $templateCache with an extra condition on the ng-edit-cell-if directive.  For example, we want row 0 to be editable and row 1 to be read only:

```
$templateCache.put("cellEditTemplate.html",
  "<div ng-cell-has-focus ng-dblclick=\"editCell()\">" +
    "   <div ng-edit-cell-if=\"!isFocused || row.rowIndex == 1\">   " +
    "       DISPLAY_CELL_TEMPLATE" +
    "   </div>" +
    "   <div ng-edit-cell-if=\"isFocused && row.rowIndex == 0\">" +
    "       EDITABLE_CELL_TEMPLATE" +
    "   </div>" +
    "</div>"
);
```